# How to Know when to repeat a loop, based on information within the loop

Tags: php

I am new to php, and still trying to grasp the concepts. 

My question is, how do i change whether or not to loop, based on the information only available once i start the loop?

This is the code i have come up with, with comments to try and explain my thinking.

I'm basically trying to get the "business done" for every page, if there is 1 or many.
NOTE: $object contains the resultset which may span pages. If it does span pages then $object->pagination will exist, otherwise it will not. $object->pagination->pages = total number of pages, and $object->pagination->pages = the current page.

```
//get first page. some how this needs to be a loop i'm guessing.
$page = 1;
$url = "api/products/page/" . $page;
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array ("Content-Type: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array ("Accept: application/json"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username-password");
        $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $object = json_decode($contents);
//$data returned with product info and pagination info if there is more than one page.


//now check in that first page to see if there is other pages set
if(isset($object->pagination)){
        while($object->pagination->page < $object->pagination->pages) {
        $page = $page+1 ;
        //do some business
    } else {//stop going through the pages}
}
```

Comment: You are checking $object->pagination->page in the while loop and incrementing $page in your code. Why so? In this case the $object->pagination->page will never be reassigned and your loop will go forever and ever? Or my understanding of your code is incorrect..?

Comment: I think you mean: `$object->pagination->page++`, to loop over all the pages. Also, `while{}else{}` is not allowed in PHP.

Comment: i'll update question to include the rst of the story with regards to what happens before any looping.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$object->pagination->page = 1;
$url = "api/products/page/" . $object->pagination->page;

//$url is used for cURL. $object returned with product info and pagination info if there is more than one page.
$object //JSON decoded object returned from cURL. 

//now check in that first page to see if there is other pages set
if(isset($object->pagination)){
    while($object->pagination->page pagination->pages) 
    {

        //do some business

        $object->pagination->page++;
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Increment after you do your business logic in the while loop.

Comment: Hey verisimilitude. No further answers. I'd be interested to see you ideas. Performance is not a huge concern as this will be a cronjob.

Comment: I got it to work. GOing off your hint of nesting loops. I just did the first page like normal, and then after that, did while(isset //pagination) { make the page number ++ and then do the whole first step again} Database now has exactly 2031 products in it!! :) Now on to the next.... :) Thanks again!

Comment: i'm sure its not the best way, but hey... cronJOBS DONE :)

Comment: Thx. Glad to know. Could you Green check it (my answer) please :).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to loop over all the pages in the object:

```
if (isset($object->pagination)) { 
    while ($object->pagination->page < $object->pagination->pages) { 
        $object->pagination->page++; // $x++ is the same as $x = $x+1
        //do some business 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't think my question is clear. You answer has helped in numerous ways in my general understanding and learning, however for this situation, i'm not sure it is going to work. I really need to loop this whole thing, the curl bit and all, so it loads the next page and then gets page 2 so i can "do some business" on that page too. Make sense?

Comment: i need to set the top value of $page to $page++.

Comment: wouldn't it then be trying to check something against an object that hasn't even been created yet? i'm going loopy thinking about this. :)

Comment: i think i'm not clear on the basics. From what i understand you can set a $var from the top of a page, with a value set inside a while loop or if loop in the middle of the page. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: Ok. Got your point. Few questions. before i can help you through. 1) $object contains your resultset which may span multiple pages, am i correct? And you are looping over your products page-by-page in the CURL call of yours?

Comment: yes $object contains the resultset which may span pages. If it does span pages then $object->pagination will exist, otherwise it will not. $object->pagination->pages = total number of pages, and $object->pagination->pages = the current page. Make sense?

Comment: Hmm.  I get it now. In this case, i think you may need to nested loops to loop through. Before I can post some code, let's hear some more inputs from the SO community. I think if we put in code containing nested loops it may cause some performance issues if we have that CURL in a loop.

Comment: ok cool. good time to go to sleep then :) saturday night on the computer, how social :) thanks for your time.

Comment: Before going please update your question likewise. The reader may not understand what you want to convey. Have a happening weekend :)

Comment: @Hidde: Any inputs on the above? Could we go for a nested loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(is_array($values){
      foreach($values as $value){
         //do some  with you value
      }
}else{
  // do something with $values
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example:

```
$x = 1;

// Loop 1 through 5
while( $x <= 5 )
{
   // Output x
   echo("$x\n");

   // Check if x is a certain value and do something different
   if($x==3)
   {
      echo("Almost there...\n");
   }

   // Increment x
   $x++;
}

// This outputs...
// 1
// 2
// 3
// Almost there...
// 4
// 5
```

Comment: thats not a loop based on the contents of the loop

Comment: I accidentally submitted before I was finished.